# JavaFX Exception: Internal graphics not initialized yet

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to load a controller in the constructor, and to do so I have to call `loader.load()` first, otherwise `getController()` returns `null`, as I've read in multiple stackoverflow answers.

```
protected static final FXMLLoader connectLoader = new FXMLLoader(GuiManager.class.getResource("/scenes/connect.fxml"));

private final ConnectController connectController;

public Gui() {

    try {
        connectLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    connectController = connectLoader.getController();
}
```

However load() throws this exception:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/user/IdeaProjects/project/target/classes/scenes/connect.fxml:13
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal graphics not initialized yet
...
```

The controller is specified in the fist line of the fxml:

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.project.gui.ConnectController">
```

And line 13 of the fxml file (referenced in the exception) is a quite innocuous

`<Image url="@../image.png" />`

Any suggestion is very welcome, thank you in advance.

Comment: Post a [mre]. This looks like a problem with the application lifecycle, so it’s unlikely anyone can figure out the issue without a complete (but minimal) runnable example.

Comment: I think your Problem has to do with the image URL (espacially with the .. -> maybe the relative path of your image is different when running your compiled code). You could try to put your Image in the same folder as your FXML file for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the start() method of Application hadn't finished executing, and the stage wasn't created yet at the time load() was called.

Good suggestions on how to test this also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582837/internal-graphics-not-initialized-yet-in-juunit-test-case)